# MVC model binding slow when using datetime, decimal, GUID and Nullable types

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, model-binding, boxing

I'm currently working on a performance issue in an ASP.Net project, when posting data back to our server. The data set is rather large containing over 1000 items, each item is an instance of the same view model.

The view model consists of over 30 properties, (strings, guids, decimals, datetimes, enums etc). The issue we have is that the model binding is taking a stupid amount of time which will affect the user experience drastically. We are talking 8-10 minutes for one post.

I'm watching the request in Fiddler and the JSON produced is fine and the request is kicked off rather quickly. When putting a breakpoint in the controller method being called it isn't hit for 8-10 minutes.

As part of my investigation I stripped down the view model, changing datetime's to doubles, Guid's to strings, enum's to integers and decimals to doubles. This cut the time to around 30 seconds for the data to hit the controller method. I'm guessing this is something to do with the framework having to box up thousands of properties into their .Net types.

Is there any other way of resolving this issue? changing the datatypes in the view model is probably going to cause alot of issues for us and alot of extra work as well.

Comment: Your editing 1000 items with 30 properties (you expect the user to edit 30000 controls in a form). Crazy!

Comment: The data is all in a grid and contains many controls that allow bulk editing of the entries, but its not me who is expecting users to do this. This is a user requirement! There will rarely be 1000 entries, and the user doesn't actually have to edit all of them, and most are prepopulated with defaults that they won't need to change

Comment: Then you should not be posting them back. Use a view model with just the properties you need and map the view models back to the data models

Comment: it doesn't make a difference as 90% of the fields are needed back in the controller, it's still going to be slow because of issues with the de serialisation and model binding in MVC. If you don't have anything useful to add then please don't reply to questions.

Comment: how about just posting back the changes rather than all rows.

Answer (score 2):

The default model binder in MVC can be very slow as it has to handle every generic model binding situation. It has to muddle about with reflection and bits of other stuff. That said, you would have hoped it was a bit more clever when dealing with lists of the same model.

I suspect you may have to look at creating a custom model binder for this situation rather than relying on the default.

This will mean implementing the IModelBinder interface and assigning it as the modelbinder for your model. Something to investigate at least

Comment: You could of just walked over to the other side of the office to tell me this! Still not a brilliant answer seeing as 90% of the information you provided me with, is what I told you 2 days ago!!